# What does Gandalf say To Galadriel in the Hobbit trailer?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-hobbit, gandalf

In the [Hobbit trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hy6O682OGI) Galadriel asks Gandalf:

> Why the halfling, Mithrandir?

And he responds:

> Because I'm afraid *mumble mumble something something*

What does he say to her? Its very hard to understand the last few words of his sentence

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I heard:

> "Why Bilbo Baggins? That is because I am afraid, and he gives me courage."

Comment: That's what I heard as well.

Comment: +1 thanks, the beard was muffling what he was saying a bit :)

Comment: Man, the more I hear about the movie, the more I think I'll skip the whole thing.  Way too many changes from the concept of the book...

Comment: @Ward - welcome to the rest of us suffering from "movie based on $book sux"

Comment: I'm afraid 2/3's of the film will be the dwarves singing dirges.

Comment: I arrived with anticipation and left with disappointment.